# How to destroy the activity when logout?

Tags: android

I am developing apps in android. In that I have login and logout activity with session management using SharedPreferences. my apps logout , store data in sharedpreferences to maintain session successfully done. when I do logout from the apps(second activity) and get rendered to first activity(login activity ) but what happen is when i clicked back button on emulator after successfully logout still again rendered to second activity and some version like 2.3.3 etc encountered exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.oj.bs/com.oj.bs.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

can anybody fix the problem. please refer following code

following is the **login activity code**

```
sessionmngr = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

                    JSONObject json_user = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    sessionmngr.createLoginSession(id,json_user.getString(KEY_UNAME), 
                            json_user.getString(KEY_UEMAIL));
                     .
                     .
```

following is the **Session Management**

```
public class SessionManager {

SharedPreferences pref;
Editor editor;
Context contxt;
//shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
 // Sharedpref file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "bookingScapePref";

// All Shared Preferences Keys
private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

public SessionManager(Context context) {
    super();
    this.contxt = context;
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
    editor.commit();
}
/**
 * Create login session
 * */
public void createLoginSession(int id,String name, String email) {

    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN,true);
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
    editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    editor.putInt(KEY_ID, id);
    editor.commit();
}
/**
 * Get stored session data
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> userDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
    userDetails.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));
    userDetails.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));
    return userDetails;
}
/**
 * Check login method will check user login status
 * */
public void checkLogin() {

    if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {
        Intent i = new Intent(contxt, LoginActivity.class);
        //closing all the activity
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        //Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        contxt.startActivity(i);
    }
}

public void logoutUser() {
    //clearing all data from sharedPreferences
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
    Intent intnt = new Intent(contxt, LoginActivity.class);
    // Closing all the Activities
    intnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    // Add new Flag to start new Activity
    intnt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    // Staring Login Activity
    contxt.startActivity(intnt);
}

/**
 * Quick check for login
 * **/
// Get Login State
public boolean isLoggedIn(){
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
}
```

}

this is **second activity** here i'm checking session

```
public class ProjectFragActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

SessionManager sessionMngr ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sessionMngr = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Login Status: " + sessionMngr .isLoggedIn(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    sessionMngr.checkLogin();
            .
            .
```

Comment: Can you post the code where the app is crashing (in `onDestroy()`)

Comment: Also post your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Hi, Use onBackpressed function in your login Screen and implement this **Intent** function. It will take you to the home screen of the phone.

Hope this will give you some solution.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution should be to call `finish();` in your second activity.

Comment: I finish the activity on destroy function.I encountered the exception like "java.lang.runtimeException unable to destroy the activity", when i pressed the back button.

Comment: @SwapnilTayade The activity has already been finished when `onDestroy()` is called. You shouldn't call `finish()` at that time. Post the code of your `onDestroy()`

Answer (score 0):

First don't call `finish()` in `destroy()`, the activity is already finishing and going away, plus that screws up with everything else. What you need to do is call `finish()` upon logging out, whatever function you have to log the person out, at the end of it, put `finish()`.